# Registering to push with Parse

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to register for push notification using parse .

on the application finish launch i have :

```
//register to push
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

Than , when i am getting this callback ,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"registered:%@",newDeviceToken);


    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:newDeviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];

}
```

the device token is good, but i get this error :

```
Error: deviceType must be specified in this operation (Code: 135, Version: 1.2.18)
```

And the device does not registered on parse's site.
Whats wrong with that function ?

Comment: Just delete app and retry again.. I think PFInstallation register your device token only first time.. Than it will show same error everytime

Comment: Did you add ApplicationID and ClientKey?

Comment: @Curnelious have you solved this issue ? if yes then please provide answer i am facing same issue. Thank you!